# How to get Header and Footer from PDF file using apache tika in java

Tags: java, pdfbox, apache-tika

I am using apache tika to crawl the content from the pdf file.The crawled content(text) contains headers and footers also.My requirement is to get the text without headers and footers.Below is my sample code to crawl the content.
Sample Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            String file = "C://Sample.pdf";
            File file1 = new File(file);
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file1);
            Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
            BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(
                    10 * 1024 * 1024);
            AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
            parser.parse(input, handler, metadata);
            String path = "C://AUG7th".concat("/").concat(file1.getName())
                    .concat(".txt");
            String content = handler.toString();
            File file2 = new File(path);
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file2.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content);
            bw.close();

    }

}
```

How to do this please suggest me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I havent found a way to parse headings or footer of a pdf using Tika. You need another api to do that such as [PDFTextSTream](http://snowtide.com/).

**EDIT:** OK.. Tika will (try to) extract raw text and metadata from the pdf.
You need to parse and analyze the raw text in order to delete headings and footers.
I suggested PDFTextStream rather than Tika because it will simplify the task of implementing an algorithm for this purpose.
When you parse a pdf with PDFTextStream you can extract TextUnits that are not simple characters but they "carry" other information too. You also have the ability to select a region of text and in addition it gives you the choice of maintaining the visual layout of each page.

@Gagravarr
XHTML output of a pdf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
**<head>**
<meta name="dcterms:modified" content="2012-11-21T16:08:42Z"/>
<meta name="meta:creation-date" content="2010-06-22T07:00:09Z"/>
<meta name="meta:save-date" content="2012-11-21T16:08:42Z"/>
<meta name="Content-Length" content="702419"/>
<meta name="Last-Modified" content="2012-11-21T16:08:42Z"/>
<meta name="dcterms:created" content="2010-06-22T07:00:09Z"/>
<meta name="date" content="2012-11-21T16:08:42Z"/>
<meta name="modified" content="2012-11-21T16:08:42Z"/>
<meta name="xmpTPg:NPages" content="20"/>
<meta name="Creation-Date" content="2010-06-22T07:00:09Z"/>
<meta name="created" content="Tue Jun 22 09:00:09 CEST 2010"/>
<meta name="producer" content="Atypon Systems, Inc."/>
<meta name="Content-Type" content="application/pdf"/>
<meta name="xmp:CreatorTool" content="PDFplus"/>
<meta name="resourceName" content="Lessons from a High-Impact Observatory The Hubble Space Telescope.pdf"/>
<meta name="Last-Save-Date" content="2012-11-21T16:08:42Z"/>
<meta name="dc:title" content="Lessons from a High-Impact Observatory: The &lt;italic&gt;Hubble Space Telescopes&lt;/italic&gt; Science Productivity between 1998 and 2008"/>
<title>Lessons from a High-Impact Observatory: The &lt;italic&gt;Hubble Space Telescopes&lt;/italic&gt; Science Productivity between 1998 and 2008</title>
**</head>**
**<body>**<div class="page"><p/>
<p>Lessons from a High-Impact Observatory: The Hubble Space Telescope’s Science Productivity
between 1998 and 2008
Author(s): Dániel Apai, Jill Lagerstrom, Iain Neill Reid, Karen L. Levay, Elizabeth Fraser,
Antonella Nota, and Edwin Henneken
Reviewed work(s):
Source: Publications of the Astronomical Society of the Pacific, Vol. 122, No. 893 (July 2010),
pp. 808-826
Published by: The University of Chicago Press on behalf of the Astronomical Society of the Pacific
Stable URL: http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/654851 .
Accessed: 21/11/2012 11:08
</p>
<p>Your use of the JSTOR archive indicates your acceptance of the Terms &amp; Conditions of Use, available at .
http://www.jstor.org/page/info/about/policies/terms.jsp
</p>
<p> .
</p>
<p>JSTOR is a not-for-profit service that helps scholars, researchers, and students discover, use, and build upon a wide range of
content in a trusted digital archive. We use information technology and tools to increase productivity and facilitate new forms
of scholarship. For more information about JSTOR, please contact support@jstor.org.
</p>................**</body>**
```

In **head** Tika gives us the metadata that it found, and in **body** it gives us the text divided in paragraphs(seems a bit clumsy too) and it also can give us annotation links. So, i don't think its very helpful.

Comment: Doesn't Tika mark up the HTML with the headers and footers in a different area of the HTML? If so, can't you just have your ContentHandler exclude those bits?

Comment: I think you are talking about parsing an HTML page and the question is about parsing a pdf. (not sure that i understood well)

Comment: Tika will turn your PDF into XHTML. I'm wondering if you can't process the output XHTML from Tika to exclude the Header and Footer, which IIRC are marked up as such in the HTML

Comment: yes Tika can return your pdf in XHTML, but have you seen the output?
I dont think its helpful.

Comment: @Gagravarr see above for an output example.

Comment: Ah, pesky. Tika will do `<div class="header">` for word documents, looks like that's an enhancement request you'll need to file for the PDF parser in Tika, as there's not matching code for PDFs sadly